# Shiny tracking of application

Tags: r, shiny

The link https://solutions.rstudio.com/data-science-admin/tracking/ will explain how to integrate shiny usage tracking of applications deployed on rstudio connect.

But similar to this, can we also see users information when the apps are deployed on shiny server pro.?  The information i need are

1. Who logged in ?
2. How long the users have stayed in the applications ?
3. When did the user logged out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using `session` object.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  login <- Sys.time()
  
  observe({
    print(session$user)
  })
  
  
  onSessionEnded(function(){
    print(Sys.time())
    print(Sys.time() - login)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks: but when u deploy this on shiny server pro. U won’t get the user name